Build Aiven's Plugins for Remote Storage into the Bitnami/Kafka Image
I have written this Dockerfile to build a custom Kafka image with remote storage to Minio S3, using Bitnami's Kafka image and Aiven's plugins:
FROM bitnami/kafka:3.9.0

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins \
    &&  mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/kafka/tiered-storage-cache

RUN curl -L https://github.com/Aiven-Open/tiered-storage-for-apache-kafka/releases/download/2024-10-23-1729694047/core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.tgz -o /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/core.tgz \
    && curl -L https://github.com/Aiven-Open/tiered-storage-for-apache-kafka/releases/download/2024-10-23-1729694047/s3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.tgz -o /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/s3.tgz

RUN tar -xzf /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/core.tgz -C /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/ \
    && rm /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/core.tgz \
    && tar -xzf /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/s3.tgz -C /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/ \
    && rm /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/s3.tgz

RUN chown -R root:root /opt/bitnami/kafka \
    && chmod -R 777 /opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins /opt/bitnami/kafka/tiered-storage-cache
# Ensure that the subfolders in tiered-storage-cache will inherit the permissions
RUN chmod g+s /opt/bitnami/kafka/tiered-storage-cache

My Kafka cluster is running in Kraft mode, with 3 controllers and 3 brokers. Below is my broker configuration:
    KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: "broker"
    KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "PLAINTEXT"
    KAFKA_CFG_SUPER_USERS: "User:sa"
    KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
    KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS: 12
    KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "PLAINTEXT"
    KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:SASL_PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT"
    KAFKA_CFG_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: "PLAIN"
    KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: "PLAIN"
    KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_CONTROLLER_PROTOCOL: "PLAIN"
    KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_USER: "sa"
    KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_PASSWORD: "000000"
    KAFKA_CONTROLLER_USER: "sa"
    KAFKA_CONTROLLER_PASSWORD: "000000"
    # CLIENT SETTINGS
    KAFKA_CLIENT_LISTENER_NAME: "EXTERNAL"
    KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS: "sa,da,va"
    KAFKA_CLIENT_PASSWORDS: "000000,111111,222222"
    KAFKA_CFG_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "io.aiven.kafka.tieredstorage=DEBUG,org.apache.kafka.common.security=DEBUG,org.apache.kafka.server.log.remote.metadata.storage=DEBUG" # Increase Tiered Storage log level
    KAFKA_CFG_REMOTE_LOG_STORAGE_SYSTEM_ENABLE: "true" # Enable Tiered Storage
    KAFKA_CFG_LOG_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 10000 # Log cleaner checks whether any log is eligible for deletion
    KAFKA_CFG_REMOTE_LOG_MANAGER_TASK_INTERVAL_MS: 5000 # Interval at which remote log manager runs the scheduled tasks like copy segments, and clean up remote log segments.
    # Remote metadata manager
    KAFKA_CFG_REMOTE_LOG_METADATA_MANAGER_CLASS_NAME: "org.apache.kafka.server.log.remote.metadata.storage.TopicBasedRemoteLogMetadataManager"
    KAFKA_CFG_REMOTE_LOG_METADATA_MANAGER_LISTENER_NAME: "PLAINTEXT"
    KAFKA_CFG_RLMM_CONFIG_REMOTE_LOG_METADATA_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
    KAFKA_CFG_REMOTE_LOG_STORAGE_MANAGER_CLASS_PATH: "/opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/*:/opt/bitnami/kafka/plugins/s3-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/*" 
    KAFKA_CFG_REMOTE_LOG_STORAGE_MANAGER_CLASS_NAME: "io.aiven.kafka.tieredstorage.RemoteStorageManager"
    KAFKA_CFG_RSM_CONFIG_CHUNK_SIZE: 4194304 # 4 MiB
    KAFKA_CFG_RSM_CONFIG_FETCH_CHUNK_CACHE_CLASS: "io.aiven.kafka.tieredstorage.fetch.cache.DiskChunkCache"
    KAFKA_CFG_RSM_CONFIG_FETCH_CHUNK_CACHE_PATH: "/opt/bitnami/kafka/tiered-storage-cache"
    KAFKA_CFG_RSM_CONFIG_FETCH_CHUNK_CACHE_SIZE: 1073741824 # 1 GiB
    KAFKA_CFG_RSM_CONFIG_FETCH_CHUNK_CACHE_PREFETCH_MAX_SIZE: 16777216 # 16 MiB
    KAFKA_CFG_RSM_CONFIG_FETCH_CHUNK_CACHE_RETENTION_MS: 600000 # 600000 ms
    KAFKA_CFG_RSM_CONFIG_CUSTOM_METADATA_FIELDS_INCLUDE: "REMOTE_SIZE"

I'm experiencing two problems:

When I run docker compose up, a topic that should be auto-created fails due to the SASL configuration.
When I remove the SASL configuration to test the remote storage function ( thus the first problem is resolved), but when I try to create a topic with the remote storage function, I get the following error while i already has the Enable Tiered Storage config on:
ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Tiered Storage functionality is disabled in the broker. Topic cannot be configured with remote log storage. (org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand)

Upon further checking of the server.properties file in the broker's container, I found that this configuration was correctly mapped: remote.log.storage.system.enable=true
It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me solve any of these problems!
